# Airodump-ng and my iPhone

Tags: wifi, ubuntu, spyware

Yesterday I run the Airodump-ng tool to check out the invisible.
I noticed that in the client section there was a somewhat familiar name of a Probe. The person that this nickname reminded is a tech-savy friend. I thought of switching my phones wifi on and off, and with each turn on the Airodump-ng tool detected my phones client with the same Probe name, which confirmed that it is my device. Today I went to that friends living place and turned on my phones wi-fi, and it found a wi-fi with a name which appeared as my iPhone when Airodump-ng was turned on. Dows this mean he was spying on me?

Comment: The wording of this question makes it quite hard to understand what you are asking.  Maybe break down and better explain what you are seeing at each step.  The evidence you may have found related to your friend potentially spying on you is not being clearly communicated.

Comment: It almost sounds like your phone is running a wifi hotspot... which your friend maybe setup on your phone using his nickname as the SSID?

Comment: 1. I run Airodump-ng on Ubuntu linux. 2. I noticed a familiar name for a device in Probe (client). 3. I immeditaely recognized the nickname which my friend uses. I start to thinker, what device could it be. 4. I turn off my iPhones wifi - it disappeared from the Airodump-ng. 5. I turn my wifi on (as in - searching for available wifi's) and it came back up again. I did this 20x more. Why isnthe Airodump-ng under the Probe showing my device in a name of my friends Wi-fi name? How is this possible?

Comment: I have been only 1x to this persons house a long time ago. He is a mobile app developer. He has never touched my phone nor asked me to do anything with it.

Comment: Do I have the green light to confront him sbout this?

Answer (score 1):

What this might be is a probe for known SSIDs by your iPhone. You might have saved his wifi and this probe might be trying to connect to a hidden SSID (your phone is probing to see if the SSID is in range). This is not abnormal.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have saved a hand full of Wi-fi, and in all 20x trials (turning iPhones Wi-fi search On-Off) the Airodump displayed my device's probe in the name of the person's Wi-fi name.

Comment: + I can test if this is true. I will connect to this person's wifi. Then I will get back home to run the Airodump-ng tool to see if the Probe's name is that of the wi-fi again. Is this a legitimate way of testing it?